# how to deduce the size of a multidimensional array in a curly brace expression of a function call with templates

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I'm currently writing a typesafe compiletime-enabled tensor class, which boils down to

```cpp
template<typename T, int... Sizes>
struct tensor {
  T elements[(Sizes * ...)];
  auto ptr() {return elements;}
  auto size() {return (Sizes * ...);}

  using value_type = T;
};
```

I wanted to write a method that allows to create a tensor with arrays as an expression, like that:

`make_tensor({1,2,3,4})` or `make_tensor({{1,2},{3,4}})`, giving a vector and a matrix. my `make_tensor` function currently looks like this:

```cpp
template<template<typename, int...> class Fill, typename Type, int... Sizes>
struct array_to_index {
  using type = Fill<Type, Sizes...>;
};

template<template<typename, int...> class Fill, typename Type, int Size, int... Sizes>
struct array_to_index<Fill, Type[Size], Sizes...> {
  using type = typename array_to_index<Fill, Type, Sizes..., Size>::type;
};

template<template<typename, int...> class Fill, typename Type>
using array_to_index_t = typename array_to_index<Fill, Type>::type;

template<typename Type, int Size>
auto make_tensor(const Type (&arr)[Size]) {
  using tensor_t = array_to_index_t<tensor, Type[Size]>;
  tensor_t tensor;
  using ptr_t = const typename tensor_t::value_type *;

  for(int i = 0; i < tensor.size(); ++i)
    tensor.elements[i] = reinterpret_cast<ptr_t>(arr)[i];

  return tensor;
}
```

I can call this with a multidimensional array if I assign it first, but the nice syntax doesn't work:

```cpp
int main() {
  //auto matrix = make_tensor({{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}}); // doesn't work
  int arr[][2] = {{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}};
  auto other = make_tensor(arr); // works
  assert(other.elements[3] == 3);
}
```

With what I gather from this [Failed to deduce bounds from initializer for multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972172/failed-to-deduce-bounds-from-initializer-for-multi-dimensional-arrays/34973290#34973290) question, my approach won't work. Is there any other way this deduction is possible (e.g with initializer lists)?

Comment: You might take inspiration from [Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549398/c-eigen-initialize-static-matrix) (but they don't provide a way to have the syntax you're looking for either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot deduce multi dimensional array bounds from nested `{{}}`.

You could deduce it by adding some tokens.

```
using namespace std;
auto arr = array{ array{1,2}, array{3,4} };

for (auto row : arr) {
    for (auto e : row) {
        std::cout << e << ",";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bb2c12296ca0495).

The `array` deduction guide tears apart the `{}` expression following and deduces the type of the `array` template.

So:

```
make_tensor(a{a{1,2},a{3,4}})
```

is possible, or even

```
tensor{ tensor{1,2}, tensor{1,2} }
```

as `make` functions are a bit passé.